How to extend methods from two classes in Object Oriented (JavaScript) Typescript?
I currently have two classes with the same methods. I would like to have a class that inherits both of them, but in which methods are extended to perform the operations in both methods.
Here is an example I have two loggers:
NativeLoggingTool:
export class NativeLoggingTool implements LoggingTool {
    private logger = new Logger();

    public debug(message: string) {
        this.logger.debug(message);
    }

    public info(message: string) {
        this.logger.info(message);
    }
}

ServiceLoggingTool:
export class ServiceLoggingTool implements LoggingTool {

    public debug(message: string) {
        Service.setLevel('debug').captureMessage(message);
    }

    public info(message: string) {
        Service.setLevel('info').captureMessage(message);
    }
}

My end result should be something like this:
export class NativeAndServiceLoggingTool implements LoggingTool {
    private logger = new Logger();

    public debug(message: string) {
        this.logger.debug(message);
        Service.setLevel('debug').captureMessage(message);
    }

    public info(message: string) {
        this.logger.info(message);
        Service.setLevel('info').captureMessage(message);
    }
}

As you can see it leads to a lot of code repetition and I'm wandering if there's any design pattern that could be used to write this in a cleaner and DRY way.
To give more context into the problem:
They are both exported as LoggingTool in a NestJS applicaton. Therefore usages are the same:
this.loggingTool.debug.... However, we export different ones depending on the environment, and now we would like to use both of them in some environments.
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I want to combine (merge) methods from two classes into one class. I tried to use inheritance, but it doesn't apply for this use case.

Could you change your NativeAndServiceLoggingTool class to hold an instance of the two other classes? Then NativeAndServiceLoggingTool.debug can call the debug method of NativeLoggingTool and ServiceLoggingTool in whichever order you need. I can add a working example if needed

Thank you, that's actually what I thought of doing:
public debug(message: string, extras?: Record<string, unknown>) {         this.nestLogger.debug(message, extras);         this.serviceLogger.debug(message, extras);     }
but I was wandering if there's a standard and cleaner way.

You can define a class that combines several LoggingTools.
class MultiLoggingTool implements LoggingTool {

    private readonly loggingTools: Array<LoggingTool>;

    constructor(loggerTools: Array<LoggingTool>) {
        this.loggingTools = loggerTools;
    }

    debug(message: string): void {
        for (let loggingTool of this.loggingTools) {
            loggingTool.debug(message);
        }
    }

    info(message: string): void {
        for (let loggingTool of this.loggingTools) {
            loggingTool.info(message);
        }
    }
}

And then use it in the following way.
let loggingTool: LoggingTool = new MultiLoggingTool(
   new Array(new NativeLoggingTool(), new ServiceLoggingTool())
);

loggingTool.debug("To log");


That looks good! I will check if it works

Thanks for the answer, unfortunately adding tools in the constructor would make the usage different from the original implementation.

I changed the first line to this one: private readonly loggingTools: Array<LoggingTool> = [new NativeLoggingTool(), new ServiceLoggingTool()]; and removed the constructor.

Why don't you use composition instead of inheritance:
function mergeLoggingTools(...loggers: LoggingTool[]): LoggingTool {
    return {
      debug(message: string) {
        loggers.forEach(logger => logger.debug(message));
      },
      info(message: string) {
        loggers.forEach(logger => logger.info(message));
      }
    };
}

const myLogger = mergeLoggingTools(new NativeLoggingTool(), new ServiceLoggingTool());
myLogger.debug('test message');

You can go with a class with similar functionality if you prefer it.
Notes:

TS type system is structural, not nominal. Thus in your example NativeLoggingTool is not needed - Logger implements LoggingTool

TS Playground

Thank you, I will try to make something like that. We have a nestJs application.

I didn't find anything better than this code bellow:
export class NativeAndServiceLoggingTool implements LoggingTool {
    private nativeLogger = new NativeLoggingTool();
    private serviceLogger = new ServiceLoggingTool();

    public debug(message: string) {
        this.nativeLogger.debug(message);
        this.serviceLogger.debug(message);
    }

    public info(message: string) {
        this.nativeLogger.info(message);
        this.serviceLogger.info(message);
    }
}

It still seems to be a bit repetitive, but it allow us to modify our loggers without modifying the NativeAndServiceLoggingTool class itself.
